# Is there any easy way to find the maximum (i.e. white) value for a given Open CV type?

Tags: opencv

If I have an Open CV matrix and I don't know what type it is (e.g. 8 bit unsigned, 32 bit float), is there an easy function that will give me the value that is used to represent white (so 255 for 8 bit unsigned, 1.0 for 32 bit float, etc)?

Comment: There isn't a built-in function to do this, sadly. You need to know the types yourself and infer the correct maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OpenCV 2.x, take a look at [Mat::depth](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) to retrieve (quoting the Docs):

> the identifier of the matrix element depth (the type of each individual channel)

From there you can calculate the value to represent the white color with a switch:

```
switch (image.depth()) {
   case CV_8U: 
       white = Scalar(255,255,255); break;
   case CV_8S:
       ...
}
```

Comment: Accepted as this appears to be the best way, but surprising there isn't something simpler built in.